# Split Tool Deleting Smaller Polygon

Tags: arcgis-pro, splitting

I'm attempting to use the split tool to divide a vector shapefile into two parts. I used a process that I've been successful with before:

Go to Edit > Split > Select my feature to split > Draw a line that goes all the way through the feature (past two edges) > then either click "finish" or double click to close my line

For some reason when I went through this process just now it split the feature along my line but then immediately erased the smaller polygon. Has anyone else had this problem and/or know how to fix it?

Comment: Split is working as expected on ArcGIS Pro 2.2.

Comment: It looks like you are dealing with multipart vector file. Select the feature that you want to split, `Start editing -> Enable advanced editing tools -> Explode`. Then use the split tool as usual.